Use `handleExceptionInternal` or return a ResponseEntity directly in ExceptionHandler?
We have the following code in our codebase (so that exceptions are logged).
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception::class)
    fun handleAllExceptions(ex: Exception, request: WebRequest): ResponseEntity<Any>? {
        logger.error("Exception caught: ", ex)
        val headers = HttpHeaders()
        headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
        val errorDetails = ProblemDetail.forStatusAndDetail(
            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            ex.message ?: "An unexpected error occurred",
        )
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, errorDetails, headers, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request)
    }

A questions has come up why we don't return ResponseEntity directly instead of calling the handleExceptionInternal method. Anyone knows why? Should we create ResponseEntity directly instead?
I have found the source code for handleExceptionInternal. Not entirely sure what the code does and when it enters the different blocks. Will it ever enter the two first if-blocks? And what is a "request attribute" (and does it matter for us)?

possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63977406/in-responseentityexceptionhandler-what-is-the-exact-difference-between-handleexc

@RyuzakiL not a duplicate. However the post contains interesting information about the purpose of the built-in methods.
